# How to reset uploading file using lightning file upload after clicking on cancel button in lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, fileupload

When I click on new button to uploading a file and click on cancel button, then again I click on new button I want to reset the previous uploaded file from there.

*Upload Medical Certificate                 
                            
                             {docName}

Cancel button
Cancel</button

JS

closeSuspendModal()
{
this.isShowSuspendModel=false;
}

get acceptedFormats() {
return ['.pdf', '.png', '.docx', '.jpg', '.jpeg'];
}

```
handleUploadFinished(event) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
    this.docId=uploadedFiles[0].documentId;
    this.docName=uploadedFiles[0].name+' uploaded successfully';
    console.log('1111'+uploadedFiles[0].documentId)
    console.log('1111'+uploadedFiles[0].name)
    
}
```

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by reset uploaded file. Could you please post your html and js files, then it is easy for us to help. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times. Instead, edit your existing post to clarify and add information. Make sure to post code _in the question body_ and use the editor's formatting tools to format it. See [ask] and [help/on-topic] for more about our format.